# Rails 4 - Set limit to included model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Many-to-Many associations like this (it's been simplified for your convenience)

```
class Product
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, through: :categorization
end

class Category
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :products, through: :categorization
end
```

I want to list out the **first 5 products of each category**

But I can't find a way to set limit to the included `product`. Below is my current query:

```
@categories = Category.includes(:products).all
```

The only solution I found is to add the condition in model like:

```
# Solutions that I don't like
class Category
  ...
  has_many :products, include: product, limit: 5
end
```

Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you create a scope on your `Product` class to return the first five objects, then you can call that scope on your relation. Like so:

```
class Product
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, through: :categorization

  scope :first_five, -> { limit(5) }
end
```

Then you can do the following:

```
@categories = Category.includes(:products)
@categories.each do |category|
  puts category.products.first_five.inspect
end
```

And you should see at most 5 products per category.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but will it occur additional sql query for each product?

Comment: I just did a test and it is indeed doing another query for every loop. So I got additional five SQL queries. Is there better way? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Conditions**

You could try this:

```
#app/models/product.rb
Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :categories, -> { limit(5) }, through: :categorization
end
```

If you look at ["Eager Loading Of Associations"](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) you can see a great demonstration of this type of idea

---

**ActiveRecord Association Extensions**

However, I think this will only yield 5 categories. If you want 5 for each category, you could also use [ActiveRecord Association Extenstions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions):

```
#app/models/product.rb
Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :categories, through: :categorization do
        def first_five
            limit(5)
        end
    end
end

@categories = Category.includes(:products).all
@categories.each do |category|
    puts category.first_five
end
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I tried both your suggestion. **First** one only limit the products if we use `Category.rewards` and not `Category.includes(:rewards)`. The **second** one produces error `undefined method "first_five"`, but isn't the second method the same as `scope`?

Comment: **note**: in the comment above I accidentally use "reward" instead of "product" because that's the real name. Using "product" is just to simplify the question =).